# Почему изменяя положение кнопки, она перестаёт работать?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 2000);

function nextSlide() {
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
  currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % slides.length;
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Raleway";
  color: #3f3f3f;
  font-weight: lighter;
  float: inherit;
  border-color: #3f3f3f;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 780px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

header {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #F0F8FF;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
  color: #979897;
  font-weight: "lighter";
  margin-top: 210px;
  border-color: #979897;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 90px;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 700px;
  float: right;
}

h2 {
  color: #3f3f3f;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-family: "Raleway";
  font-size: 23px;
}

#slides {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  height: 640px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 650px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.showing {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slide {
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
}

.picture {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  height: 640px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 650px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Raleway";
  color: #3f3f3f;
  font-weight: lighter;
  border-bottom-color: #3f3f3f;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.btn {
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  border-color: #979897;
  border-width: 1px;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: solid;
  font-size: 20px;
  font: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font: #979897;
}

.btn:hover {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background: palegoldenrod;
  border-color: #979897;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn:focus {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background: #979897;
  ;
  border-color: #979897;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn:active {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background: #979897;
  border-color: #979897;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.button {
  margin-right: 110px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<header>
  <p>Help Cooperation Language</p>
  <h1>COOKING FOOD </h1>
</header>
<div class="button">
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="SEARCH FOR THE RECIPE" class="btn" onClick=();>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="block-for-slider">
  <div id="viewport"></div>
  <ul id='slides'>
    <li class="slide showing"> <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c852124/v852124380/1456e4/Icw8qDLicos.jpg" alt="Fruits" class="picture"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="318578.jpg" alt="" class="picture"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="caption.jpg" alt="" class="picture"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="tacos.jpg" alt="" class="picture"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<footer>
  <h2>Delicious recipes with detailed step by step description and photos. Convenient search, selection of ingredients, calorie counting, menu preparation, reviews and comments of users.</h2>
</footer>
```

Comment: Каким образом она должна сработать? К ней не привязана ни одна функция

Comment: До использования margin всё работало

Comment: Что она должна выполнять? И margin какого элемента остановил её работу?

Comment: Просто хотя бы чтобы при наведении менялся цвет. И margin для класса button перестал работать

Answer (score 0):

Всё дело в списке `<ul>` с id='slides', он своей высотой перекрывает вашу кнопку.

Comment: Спасибо! То есть, мне нужно уменьшить высоту?

Comment: При position:relative элементу автоматически ставится display: block, и в этом случае, без явного указания длины, он будет занимать всю длину родителя. Вывод: поставьте width длиною ваших картинок

Comment: Спасибо огромное!